# android:dividerPadding has no effect

Tags: android

This theme works fine, referencing three custom styles for the 3 parts of the ActionBar's tabs.

But the "dividerPadding" has no effect on any of them - running on API 17 devices.

```
 <style name="Theme.AppEmptyTitleBar" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AB</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ABT</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ABTB</item>
    </style>

<style name="AB" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">20dip</item>
</style>
<style name="ABT" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">20dip</item>
</style>
<style name="ABTB" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">20dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I know it may sound strange, but do you actually apply this style to the `Activity`? also, does placing e.g. `<item name="android:divider">@null</item>` in `ABTB` hide all dividers?

Comment: Fair question, but yes - I didn't paste the other elements of the style (that prove it IS showing in app) only to simplify the SO question.

Comment: re: "android:divider = @null" -- yes, this hides the dividers

Comment: yeah, I thought so, just tried to eliminate obvious cases. I just tried in API 17 and it works pretty well - padding `1dip`: http://www.anony.ws/iVK and `20dip`: http://www.anony.ws/iVN (I used the magnifying glass icon as the divider for simplicity). what API have you tried your theme on? was it emulator or a real device?

Comment: Both device and emulator ...

Comment: Hmm what happens if you dont set an explicit divider? Could it be that the default divider is somehow hardcoded to ignore padding? (Seeing as the offiical docs for actionbar have an enormous bug already, i dont trust them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `dividerPadding` attribute is (as far as I know) only applicable to the `*ActionBar.TabBar` style.

I've tested your style using a very basic application making use of the native `ActionBar` and a device providing API 17. I've set the `dividerPadding` attribute to different values and left the rest of the attributes with default values. Here are the results:

- `dividerPadding="0dip"`:

[image]

- `dividerPadding="15dip"`:

[image]

- `dividerPadding="20dip"`:

[image]

As you can see, divider is gone on the last image. So my first advice would be to check if you see it at all. Other than that, the `dividerPadding` seems to be working as expected.

My second advice comes from the way Android platform handles style resources placed in different `values-*` directories. My hunch is that you might be making use of your action bar styles in the default `values` directory. If you then happen to provide an override of these styles in a `values-*` directory which is compatible (e.g. `values-vX` where `X <= 17`), the styles from `values` will be ignored. As an example, consider that you've placed these sample styles in the `values/styles.xml` file:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ABTB</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ABTB" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If you then place this style definition in `values-v17/styles.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    </style>
</resources>
```

it will override the `AppTheme` style, effectively "resetting" (technically: ignoring) the whole `actionBarTabBarStyle` style (including the `dividerPadding` attribute value). In effect, you won't see any changes made to the `ABTB` style.

**Edit**

Yup, I assumed you know that, sorry :( The `dividerPadding` value applies only to:

- Top and bottom of divider when the `TabWidget` (it's the container of tab labels) draws tabs horizontally.
- Left and right sides of divider when the `TabWidget` draws tabs vertically.

Which is exactly what you see in the screenshots. As far as I know, you have to set `divider` to a drawable which will force additional padding. I believe the `layer` drawable will be great for that purpose because you can set padding explicitly for every layer.

Comment: Have I misunderstood the docs? I expected a dividerPadding of 20dip to push the tabs either side of it 40 dip pixels apart.

Comment: Thanks. I double-checked the docs, and this "subtlety" isn't mentioned. Gah. Hate, hate HATE Android's crappy docs!