# LsitView Divider Padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, padding, divider

I would like to add padding to the top and bottom of a listview divider.

I have tried inserting **android:dividerPadding="10dp"**
 property into my xml layout file.

But nothing happens. What do I need to change? Thank you all for your help.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="backgroundDescription"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_01" >
    </ImageView>

    <com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757829/androiddividerpadding-has-no-effect

Answer (score 0):

Would increasing the [dividerHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3adividerHeight) give you the effect you are looking for? Or try adding the padding to the divider drawable that will be the items in the list.

Comment: I am looking to make space between the divider top and bottom. Not increase the size of the divider.

Answer (score 0):

I follow a different approach to this, since drawablePadding doesn't give directions as Top, bottom etc.

What I do is add `android:layout_marginTop` to the first item in the List and `android:layout_marginBottom` to the last.

This automatically makes some space around the divider from top and bottom. (Not the conventional way, but works) :)